# Calculation of error limits on linear least squares coefficients

Tags: algorithms, least-squares

I am developing software to find a 'good' solution for the over-constrained problem $Ax=b$, where

- $A$ is a known matrix $A_{i,j}$, $i=1,\ldots, M$, $j = 1,\ldots,N$, $M > N$,
- $b$ is a known vector $b_i$, $i=1,\ldots,M$, but may contain noise or measurement error, and
- $x$ is an unknown vector $x_j$, $j=1,\ldots,N$

using least squares and a singular value decomposition algorithm I found in *Numerical Recipes*. All works fine (i.e., produces a consistent solution for x) but now I want **a measure of the uncertainty in each of the $x_j$ terms**. Can anybody point me to an algorithm or reference to help calculate this. Any sensible **measure of the uncertainty** is OK as I just need an indication of the relative 'goodness' of each coefficient.

Note: I don't want an algorithm to solve for $x$, I already have that using QR decomposition. What I want is a measure of the uncertainty or error or variance (insert suitable term here) in the individual coefficients of $x$ that are returned by the least squares fit.

Comment: Usually this problem is solved using QR decomposition...

Comment: Yes - that is what I use. QR decomposition gives me a best fit vector x, but does not give me an uncertainty or error in x.

Comment: You should look at some basic material on linear regression...

Comment: maybe look at the [standard error of the regression](http://onlinestatbook.com/2/regression/accuracy.html), which of course gets you into the pandora's box of error specification, etc... but the [variance-covariance matrix](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/68151/how-to-derive-variance-covariance-matrix-of-coefficients-in-linear-regression) of $x$ is a start.